# Share cookies in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies

I have an existing web application which runs on

```
https://subdomain.example.com
```

Now I like to have additional subdomains

```
https://subdomain2.example.com
```

How can I set the following using Spring MVC so that the user will not be prompted for authentication again after being redirected from the first domain to the second domain ?

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this  controller example, but keep in mind 2 things:

- putting an arbitrary fixed domain will not allow you to access the cookie when you work in your local environment if you connect to 127.0.0.1.
- your cookie could be read by all the subdomain present on that host(example.com), not only by the ones you want.

Class:

```
package com.test.foo;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping("/cookie")
    public String setCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
        String value = "value";
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", value);
        cookie.setPath("/");//<-- important
        cookie.setDomain("example.com");
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        return "foo/index";//your view
    }
}
```

Comment: When i do that and redirect to subdomain.. the cookie is not persisted! whats should i do!??

Comment: @manukyanv07 cookie expires when session end by default, use cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10); to persist it

Comment: I am not exactly sure but maybe you can test with by putting these configurations to `etc/hosts` file:

`127.0.0.1 example.com`
`127.0.0.1 subdomain1.example.com`
`127.0.0.1 subdomain2.example.com`
`127.0.0.1 subdomain3.example.com`